# How to extract first part of tuple due to the second part in a list range

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```py
max([val for idx, (id, val) in list(group)])
```

`group` contains something like:

```py
[(0, (50, 2318.5666619047615)), (1, (51, 2318.937616190476)), ...]
```

I want to choose `max` value from a list range based on `val`. It works and returns maximum value.
But I need the `id` which is related to the maximum value.

I don't know how to do that really. I need your help me, I'll appreciate that! Thanks.

Comment: What does group contains example ?

Comment: @KasimSharif `[(0, (50, 2318.5666619047615)), (1, (51, 2318.937616190476)), ...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a tuple of the values you want, the first item will be considered in `max()`

```
max([(val, id) for idx, (id, val) in list(group)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort them base on val and get the first id:

```
sorted(list(group), key=lambda x: x[1][1], reverse=True)[0][1][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking following code:

```
d_dict = {}
for idx, (id, val) in list(group):
    d_dict[val] = id
print(d_dict[max(d_dict.keys())])
```